# PHP loop with null check and multiple data query and echo (+ smaller if possible)

Tags: php, loops

I need to get the most recent member input from a form.

There are multiple fields in this form.

This is for a Joomla!

Here is what I have so far...

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName("ABC1", "ABC2", "ABC3", "ABC4", "ABC5", "ABC6", "ABC7"));
// this goes on up to 150 but I'm testing it out with the first 7.  


$query->from($db->quoteName('data_from_the_form_in_db'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('created_by') . ' LIKE '. $usr_id);
//Trying to get the data for specific user.  (Bonus) Not sure yet how to only get the last form input.


$db->setQuery($query);
$res = $db->loadRow();

for ($a='F0'; $a++;){
    echo $a. "\n";
    echo "</br>";

    if (isset($res [$a])) if ($res [$a] != "") { 
        echo "Err.."; exit; 
    }

    echo (isset($res [$a]));
    echo "</br>";

    if  ($a > "F150"); {
       break;
    }

}
echo "the end";
?>
```

I am playing around with the code and I get into multiple problems with this.

Sometimes I get undefined index, sometimes I get undefined offset, sometimes I get only the first cell echoed.  Also (Bonus), I was wondering what would be the smallest code for all this.  But all in all, I just want something that works. :)

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your question. If you use auto increment for the id, you can use the SQL `MAX()`.

Comment: The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column. What I need is to print all the fields that are not NULL. And it would need to be the most recent input from the user. (or the last from he filled out and sent in) @frz3993 or maybe I don't undersyand your idea :)

Comment: I think there is just too much wrong with this code for anything other than a tutorial. Maybe you should read some docs on the Joomla site, or look at some code that comes in the Joomal core for a idea how to do things like this

Comment: ok sure.  I did figure out what @frz9339 said however.  with MAx() I can get the lastest date. (and thus the most recent input by the user.

Comment: Tried looking for some for some time but nothing like I want to do.  It gets complicated when I try to mix all the different stuff in order to get what I need.  But looking at core files is good plan. thanks @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it to work like this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usr_id = $user->get('id');

   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
   $query="SELECT * FROM #__table WHERE created_by = $usr_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $rows=$db->loadObjectList();

   for($a=0; $a<count($rows);$a++){
      $row=$rows[$a];
      $id=$row->id;
   }

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($rows);


<?
```